# Diagnosing cause of slow performance in MXD

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, performance

Every now and then I'll have an MXD that suddenly begins to not only draw at agonisingly slow speeds, but also become sluggish in general. As a routine solution, I generally run MXD doctor, remove unnecessary layers, clear results, and remove layers one by one til I identify the problem.

However, I am wondering if there is a way to quickly return diagnostics that would identify problematic layers in the first instance. The in-built 'Analyze Map...' function has not generally been helpful in these cases. Is there a way to programmatically return the drawing time of each layer - or any other creative solutions to return helpful info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should try [PerfQAnalyzer](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2012/04/03/new-arcgis-performance-calibration-tool/):

> Ever wonder how long your Desktop application takes to render mapped
>   features on a layer to layer basis? Or have you ever needed to know
>   the time it takes to edit mapped features from a particular edit
>   version?
>
> ...
>
> The PerfQAnalyzer  tool is a free, unsupported, downloadable tool
>   offered to the Esri user community which can run as a stand-alone
>   ArcGIS Engine application or as an ArcMap add-in.